# Is there a way to call a variable from karate-config.js that contains the reusable feature file path?

Tags: karate

I'm starting to use Karate to create API tests and i have multiple reusable feature files. So i have created variables in the the karate-config.js that contain each the reusable feature files paths but it does not work for me?
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do this in karate-config.js :

```
config.reusableFeature = 'classpath:tools/reusableFeature.feature';
```

Then, in any feature, you can call this :

```
Then def response = call read(reusableFeature)
```